# React Redux : use Selector is called before dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm creating a react app with redux.
I need the lists of french departements for all pages in my app, so I put it in redux state.

I dispatch the action in the App component in the useEffect hook (Note I use an other useEffect in the component, but when the action is in the other block it's not working too)

I have a page where I need to use this list, so I select it with the useSelector hook.
But it returns an empty object, I have an error telling me `dpts.map is not a function`

I think the action is dispatching after the page has rendered, because I when I log the response of the api call in the action, it appears after the log of the useSelector result.

I'm using another state property in another page, but it seems to work with the other page.

App.jsx

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getDpts());
}, [dispatch])
```

Here is the action associated with :

dpts.actions.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const GET_DPTS = "GET_DPTS";
export const getDpts = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios({
                method: "get",
                url: "https://geo.api.gouv.fr/departements",
            });
            console.log("done : " + res)
            dispatch({ type: GET_DPTS, payload: res.data });
        } catch (err) {
            (err) => console.log("DPTS FETCH ERROR --- " + err);
        }
    };
};
```

Map.jsx

```js
function DptCtl() {
    // Control
    const map = useMap();

    // List of dpts and provinces
    const dpts= useSelector(dptsSelector);
    console.log(dpts);

    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" list="dpt-ctl-list" placeholder="Filtrer par département"/>
            <datalist id="dpt-ctl-list">
                {dpts.map((dpt, index) => 
                    <option value={dpt.code} key={index}>{dpt.nom}</option>
                )}
            </datalist>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are initializing your state in the reducer.

for example you create a reducer with this initial state:

```
const initialState={}
```

later, based on actions, the state changes to this:

```
   {dpts:someDataArray}
```

the problem is that you have a `dpts.map` somewhere in your app, since `dpts` is `undefined` in the beginning you receive that error that `dpts.map` is not a function.

the solution to this is simply put dpts in the initialState as an empty array:

```
    const initialState={dpts:[]}
```

if that is not the issue with your code, meaning `dpts` isn't undefined  in the initialState, it is probably initialized as a string or an object which don't have `map` methods.

Comment: It works fine ! Thank you !

Comment: I am using same mechanism to get the user in the initialization of App.tsx, so I need to set the property user to null initially. hence, I face the same error. is there any workaround?